# Could not find the main class - в чём проблема?

Tags: java

Чего программа не запускается? Все настроил по инструкции, но не хочет Run и ппц. Создает `Text.class`.

```
java MyFirstApp
Process started >>>
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MyFirstApp : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: MyFirstApp.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" <<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Вот сам код:

```
public class MyFirstApp { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello world!"); 
    } 
}
```

На команду

```
javac MyFirstApp.java
```

компилятор отвечает

```
javac: file not found: MyFirstApp.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: JDK JDR установил, даже по 2 версии что ли 65 и 66 с официального сайта

Comment: `Could not find the main class` не указан основной класс для запуска

Comment: Покажите код и то, как вы получили class-файл

Comment: Ребята это само простое, начальное задание:                                  public class MyFirstApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
}

Comment: @ЖеняЛитвинчук вы указали что нужно запускать класс `MyFirstApp` ?

Comment: cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
javac $(FILE_NAME)
java $(NAME_PART)   ------ это в Compile and Run

Comment: В какой IDE компилируете?

Comment: В notepad ++ делаю, настроил компиляцию по инструкции http://setup-steps.blogspot.com/2013/05/notepad-nppexec-add-java-compiler.html

Comment: Что я делаю не так? @Saidolim Could not find the main class не указан основной класс для запуска --- а как указать правильно?

Comment: Зачем так извращаться? Писать в блокноте. Вы переменные среды настроили правильно? Попробуйте в командной строке написать: java -version Что пишет?

Comment: Я только начал учиться... потому нам посоветовали так начать data3.floomby.com/files/share/27_12_2015/12/PZE3zwXBY0WVOyQ7CNAAQ.jpg

Comment: Установите NetBeans и учитесь на здоровье.

Comment: @Владимир, использовать IDE - вредный совет для человека, который только начал изучение. Он должен понять, что откуда вызывается и как работает. И кроме того, не всегда можно запустить IDE.

Comment: @LEQADA Возможно да, а возможно и нет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте сделать в командной стороке следуюшее

```
javac MyFirstApp.java
java MyFirstApp
```

должно работать

---

из фото (в комментах)

> c:/>javac MyFirstApp.java
>   javac: File not found: MyFirstApp.java
>   Usage: javac  
>   use -help for a list of possible options

Вам нужно скопировать `MyFirstApp.java` в `c:\` или это команду запустить из той папки где находится файл

Comment: data3.floomby.com/files/share/27_12_2015/12/q4RBKEKw0qUjwZKLxbbrQ.jpg                                         Выходит не хочет запускаться (Run) стадия чего-то... только не пойму чего, сделал вроде все по пунктам

Comment: у вас еще не скомпилировался. прочитайте первые 3 строки. не смог найти файл `MyFirstApp.java` путь не правелный

Comment: В командной строке выводит (Видно неправильно путь к папке был: data3.floomby.com/files/share/27_12_2015/13/D11xpmA62kac1ZPUYa3Xew.jpg) , а в Nodpad++ падлюка не хочет выводить.

Comment: @ЖеняЛитвинчук ну вот, работает же ))

Comment: Не работает в Nodpad++ хрен знает чего... видать где-о что-то не доделал я:

Comment: Вообщем получилось, наверное проблема была в том, что что-то было не установлено, переустановил, обновил, все работает) Всем большое спасибо)